# Vagrant keeps losing file doing provision

Tags: windows, vagrant

I'm running into an odd behavior on the latest version of vagrant in a Windows7/msys/Virtualbox environment setup, where after executing a `vagrant up` command I get an error with rsync; 'file has vanished: "/c/Users/spencerd/workspace/watcher/.LISTEN' doing the provisioning stage.

Since google, irc, and issue trackers have little to no documentation on this issue I wonder if anyone else ran into this and what would the fix be?

And for the record I have successfully build a box using the same vagrant file and provisioning script. For those that want to look, the project code is up at https://gist.github.com/denzuko/a6b7cce2eae636b0512d, with the debug log at gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

After digging further into the directory structure and running into issues with git pushing code up I was able to find a non-existant file that needed to be removed after a reboot.

Thus, doing a reboot and a `rm -rf -- "./.LISTEN\ \ \ \ \ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ 100\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  "` did the trick.